# Linking the new Google Api To Xcode 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I am fairly new to xcode and objective C in general, but have done a fair share in Microsoft.Net and visual studio.

I have just check out the latest google api objective c project. I am looking to add this as a static library to my xcode 4 project.

What i have done:

1. Add the project file to my existing project.
2. Link up the dependency on my project build phases
3. Under Build settings, I have enter -ObjC -lxml2 -all_load
4. I have build it without error. By running Shift + B.

But my issue is that when i try to enter #import "GTLTasks.h" i get an error no such file or directory.

Do i have to add the respective Service by itself? If so where should i add the files to the GTLxcode.project or my own project?

The service i am talking about is located in the following path source/services/

Sorry if i doesn't make sense as I am still exploring around in xcode and objective c.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, I have managed to resolved this issue.

1. Under the Build Settings of the xcode project, **Other linker flags**

   -ObjC -all_load
2. Followed by **Header Search Paths**

   $(SRCROOT)/YourFolder/

Where your project folder is located this is where you will place your source files from google.